# Mobile Blazor Bindings Example - Intellisense Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor

I am following this video on YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doaMSHQtXYQ

Problem is, my VS 2019 intellisense is not working properly... for example

[Intellisense errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Lls.png)

[More intellisense errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB1Eq.png)

I've installed the latest .NET core SDK, the mobile blazor bindings template, and the ASP .NET module for VS 2019... but nothing seems to help.

I'm using VS 16.7.5

Comment: Mobile Bindings is still experimental, VS support will follow at a distance. So for now, just ignore those squiggly lines. Do abuild to see if you have real errors.

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman, that's totally fine. Problem is when I actually try running everything I get a blank page now (everything was working fine). I'll try and figure out what I've done wrong but I was essentially following the tutorial in that video. Will have another look though. Thanks :)